# Django form is not valid

Tags: django, authentication

I am able to successfully sign up. When the user is signed up, they are signed in successfully. But after that the separate login doesn't work. I have pretty much copied and pasted the code from the codes for signing up and I have no clue what is wrong here.

here is the forms.py:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=["username","password","email"]




class Login(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=["username","password"]
```

here is the views.py:

```
class singup(View):
    form_class=UserForm
    template_name='users/index.html'


    def get(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(None)
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})

    def post(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user=form.save(commit=False)

            username=form.cleaned_data['username']
            password=form.cleaned_data['password']

            user.set_password(password)

            user.save()

            user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request,user)
                    return render(request,'home/index.html',{'username':username})

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})




class loginView(View):
    form_class=Login
    template_name='users/login.html'

    def get(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(None)
        return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})

    def post(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


            login(request,user)

            return render(request, 'home/index.html')


        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

HTML code :

```
"<h1> Sign In</h1>

<div class="container">
    {{ form.errors }}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

    <form action="" method="post">

        {% csrf_token %}
        username <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <br>
        <br>

        password <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <br>
        <br>


        <input type="submit" value="login">

    </form>
</div>"
```

I think the problem here is that it doesn't enter the "form.is_valid()" portion in the loginView!!!

Comment: show your forms and also post the stack trace as well

Answer (score 0):

In you code, after authenticating user by:

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

You need to add two checks,

For example:

```
if not user:
    return False

if not user.is_active:
    retuen False
```

Because, When you authenticate a user by 'authenticate' function, it return user object if login credentials are correct, otherwise return None or AnnonymousUser.

You need to make sure that login credentials are correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. 

But I think the code does not even enter the "form is valid" section. It just jumps to "return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})"

Comment: It might be returning on your index page. Please make sure that user is getting registered properly at the time of sign up. If you can show me registration code, I can help regarding this.

Comment: I have edited the post. 

I believe the sign up should be ok. Because when I fill in the sign up form, it is redirected to the right page. I have also checked this in the admin page and the new users show.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check the method you use to create user is `User.objects.create_user(username=xxx,password=xxx)` not `User.objects.create(username=xxx,password=xxx)`

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

But I think the problem is that the form is not valid. I don't know if this is related to what you have mentioned here or not